# I would like to stop the page scrolling down with the space bar to use it with another function

Tags: javascript

In pure Javascript, I have made a function that turns a toggle button on and off using the space bar (key 32) but I would like it to stop making the page scroll down as well. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you check to make sure the key pressed was the space bar, add `e.preventDefault()` or whatever you named your event as in your parameters.